# Textview limit 140 Characters not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, textview

I know this question already asked multiple times but I could not able to solve my problem with available solutions.

I applied all solutions which are available on other stack overflow threads.

**Requirements :**

If string length is more than 140 than show only 140 characters and at last add ".." at last.
If string is less than 140 characters then no need to append ".." at last.

**What I have tried:**

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvIssueBody"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLength="140"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="@dimen/detail_text_size"/>
```

I have tried above code but it is not working and I tried all other properties mixture also but It is not working.

Shall I have to do with `str.subString(0,141)` option? There is no way to limit 140 characters using textview property?

Thanks to all in advanced. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to get this to work exactly as you want with a built in TextView.  First off, a TextView will not allow anyone to add more than maxLength characters.  So if they try to add 200 characters, the last 60 would be dropped.  This means even 141 won't work if you want to keep that data.  And Elipsize doesn't ellipsize where you want it-  it ellipsizes where it needs to in order to fit the text on screen.  You can't force it to do so after a given length.

What you want really need is a custom view or a subclass of TextView, so you can override onDraw to draw a different string than the set text (a hand ellipsized version of it).

Comment: nice answer, It is better to use subString when I am going to do setText on textview.